# facebook messenger chat bot with Watson conversation api Context variable manipulation

Tags: facebook-graph-api, watson-conversation

I am facing a problem with Facebook meseger chat- bot ,problem is with Context variable storing and update .
My code is divided in two parts 
_________**********_________
part 1:

```
    var index = 0;
Facebookcontexts.forEach(function(value) {
console.log(value.From);
if (value.From == sender_psid) {
FacebookContext.context = value.FacebookContext;
console.log("Inside foreach "+JSON.stringify(FacebookContext.context));
contextIndex = index;
}
index = index + 1;
});
```

Here I have created an array named Facebookcontexts to store contexts for different users.This is where I am getting position of the user in a Facebookcontexts array which is used for later .

_________**************_____________
part 2:

```
if((FacebookContext.context==null)||(Facebookcontexts.find(v=>v.From==sender_psid)==undefined)){
Facebookcontexts.push({"From":sender_psid,"FacebookContext":response.context})
console.log("I am where sender is unknmown"+JSON.stringify(Facebookcontexts)+"\n"+Facebookcontexts.length);
}
else if(Facebookcontexts.find(v=>v.From==sender_psid)!=undefined){
Facebookcontexts[contextIndex].FacebookContext=response.context;
console.log("I am at where I know the sender"+JSON.stringify(Facebookcontexts)+"\n"+Facebookcontexts.length);
}
```

I am deciding to create a new record or update old one in if and else

Issue:
My Issue is every time  if((FacebookContext.context==null)||(Facebookcontexts.find(v=>v.From==sender_psid)==undefined)) is getting checked and for that array length is 1 all the time
I will look for some help from you guys.
Thanks ins advance

Comment: How are you using Facebook Messenger with Watson Conversation, is it with botkit-middleware, Conversation connector or via other means? From reading over the above it seems an individual code issue?

Comment: Hello @data_henrik
I am using node server where I am manipulating conversation-Context for facebook

Comment: I would recommend to take a look at https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/botkit-middleware

Comment: I have already checked on that but couldn't figure anything out.